# How Do I Sum the Total Of The Column Values If some Row Value Is Not Available in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to `total sum` column values, if some row value is not available in table, actually I got the `total sum value` but sum ~row value is not available~ the totalsum is showing like `NaN`...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UerLpdnc40aC8XSOPErE?p=preview)   **For Example** :- in table all row value is available means `amt` values total sum answer I got 5775.30, then in table if some row value is not available means `amount payment`  values  total sum showing like `NaN`, Expecting answer like `200`  , If any one knows the solution help to us thanks....

- In table column all values is available we got exact answer and total sum also.
- But in table, a single row value of `amount payment` is not available means the total sum values is showing like `NaN` ... so wt we expecting if the some row value is not available the total sum should be calculate rest of the values ...expecting `amount payment` answer like 200...please look at [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UerLpdnc40aC8XSOPErE?p=preview)

**My controller:-**

```
    .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
})
```

**My Html:-**

```
<td >{{mani.amt}}</td>

  <td >{{mani.amount_payment }}</td>
```

**My Data:-**

```
        {
    "_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
    "remarks": "-",
    "status": "pending",
    "amt": "1925.10",
    "cheque_currency": "Rs",
    "cheque_value": "300",
    "amount_payment": "1,925.10",
    "debitnote_no_payment": "3",
    "supplier_name": "karikalan",
    "buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
    },

    {
    "_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
    "remarks": "-",
    "status": "pending",
    "amt": "1925.10",
    "cheque_currency": "Rs",
    "cheque_value": "300",
    "amount_payment": "1,925.10",
    "debitnote_no_payment": "3",
    "supplier_name": "karikalan",
    "buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
    },

  {
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "1925.10",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"amount_payment": "",
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},
```

I have created Plunker for reference:- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UerLpdnc40aC8XSOPErE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed some code of your: Check for isNAN function of javascript

angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {

```
  var keyval;
  if(isNaN(parseFloat(v[key])))
  keyval=0;
  else
  keyval=parseFloat(v[key]);
  sum = sum + keyval;
});
```

Comment: hey @ Simanchal thanks for your valuable answer, can you please update above given answer in plunker as well to know the solution, thanks

Comment: Check the plunkr now

Answer (score 0):

The method parseFloat() will return NaN if the value is not a valid number. So you get the result as NaN. Skip all the invalid values. Example below. Hope this helps.

```
angular.forEach(data, function(v,k){
           var value = parseFloat(v[key]);
           if(isNaN(value)) {
             return;
           }
           sum = sum + value; 
        });
```

Comment: hey thanks for your valuable answer, can you please update above given answer in plunker as well to know the solution, thanks